# Ubuntu : 'Login-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure, ubuntu

I have installed Powershell in my Ubuntu machine. When I enter `Login-AzureRmAccount` into PowerShell, I get error as below:

```
PS> Login-AzureRmAccount                                                                                              
Login-AzureRmAccount : The term 'Login-AzureRmAccount' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Login-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Login-AzureRmAccount:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
```

When I enter `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh`, I didn't get any result.

PowerShell version:

```
powershell -version
powershell v6.0.0-alpha.17
```

How to solve the above error?

Comment: you can try "Get-Module -ListAvailable " to see all the modules and see azure is available or not. if not it is not installed.

Comment: Hi, what is your ubuntu version? Ubuntu 14.0.4 or 16?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the Azure PowerShell module first:

```
#Azure RM NetCore Preview Module Install
powershell Install-Module AzureRM.NetCore.Preview
powershell Import-Module AzureRM.NetCore.Preview
```

This is my test.

```
root@shui:/home# powershell 
PowerShell 
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS /home> Login-AzureRmAccount                                             
VERBOSE: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://aka.ms/devicelogin and enter the code F2RKUXRNE to authenticate.
```

For more information please refer to this [link](http://jessicadeen.com/tech/updated-powershell-core-and-azurerm-netcore-preview-module-install-scripts-for-ubuntu-and-os-x/).

Comment: It works now. What is the use install PowerShell version firstly?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Why I need to execute "powershell Install-Module AzureRM.NetCore.Preview" and "powershell Import-Module AzureRM.NetCore.Preview"?

Comment: You only install PowerShell not install Azure PowerShell. They are different.

Comment: Hi, you could check the [install script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jldeen/SVCC-AzureMgmtxplat/master/install/16.04/ps6.14_16.04_install.sh).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139728/discussion-between-karan-and-walter-msft).